# Forwarding apache request to a c++ program

Tags: c++, linux, apache, connector

I am basically looking for tips and tricks on how to approach that problem.

I have a Server Software (Linux), which is written in C++. What I need to do is
to provide some information, that is generated inside that software, via
a http call to the apache webserver.

Of course it would be possible to store the data in the database and write a servlet for it, or use IPC to get the data, but I want to keep it simple and bundled in one file. And also I want to know if the idea would work.

So the workflow would look like:
Client -> Apache Webserver -> C++ Software

Is there any existing library or something that could handle the Apache -> C++ connection? Or would it be something like just redirecting the request to a socket in c++ and do it manually? Basically something like the tomcat connector.

#### EDIT

Please note that the server software is running permanently in the background, and should not be "started" by the call

Comment: Seems like you're looking for CGI.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will wait for more replies, but I am now thinking of adding a python cgi script, that will make a RPC to the c++ program, as that RPC already exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options.

[CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) is simple and has been around forever.  Under CGI, the web server would spawn a separate process for every web request.  As you mentioned in your comment, you could write a CGI script that makes RPC calls to your C++ program.

[FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/) is an alternative to CGI; instead of spawning a separate process for every web request, it defines a protocol for letting the web server dispatch multiple web requests to a single long-running process.  It works quite well for web applications.  However, for your scenario, where you have a preexisting server process that needs to add a web interface, it may not work as well; based on my limited understanding, web servers typically expect to start and stop the long-running FastCGI processes themselves (in response to incoming requests, server load, idle time, etc.) instead of connecting to preexisting FastCGI processes.  (Most servers would let you reconfigure this, I think, but it's not the default.)

You can also always embed a web server like [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) or [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) in your C++ process and set up Apache to proxy requests to it.  This might be your best approach.  (Mongoose, for example, is *extremely* easy to embed.)

Finally, you can use a full-fledged Apache module (either redesign your C++ server as an Apache module or have an Apache module to communicate with your C++ service).  This is probably more complicated than you want to do, although there are existing projects like [CPPSERV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPPSERV) that take this approach.

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking about the possibility of including a webserver. But I had libmicrohttp in my mind. Need to check out Mongoose, cpp-netlib and libmicrohttp and test which one fits the best. If they don't work in the way I need it, I may go to the CGI/RPC method, or write a simple webserver myself.